# I am creating an SPFx web part which shows a diagram from another third party website. I am using the embedded code inside web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am creating an SPFx web part which shows a diagram from another third party website. I am using the embedded code inside web part. the script I am using is:

```
<h3 class="website-title"><a href="https://www.website.com">300.10.10. Motor Renewal - Mig v Renewal </a></h3>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://editor.website.com/mashup/website.js"></script>

<script type="text/plain">

{

    url: "https://editor.website.com/p/model/ed376f03cbc04de7b663c744d9272305",

    authToken: "",

    overflowX: "fit",

    overflowY: "fit",

    zoomSlider: true

}

</script>

<a class="website-logo" href="https://www.website.com" rel="external"><img src="https://editor.website.com/mashup/img/website.png" alt="modeling BPMN notation BPMN editor" /></a>
```

But I am getting a CORS error in the console. The diagram is not displaying.

Comment: If you don't need the dynamic image (from external site or your SharePoint site), you can try adding the images directly in your SPFx solution and refer them directly from the solution.

Comment: the above script which i posted is the embed diagram code from the third party site. the zoomslider functionality should be there along with the diagram image. Need a dynamic image only.